# create pyspark dataframes with names from list

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, databricks

I want to create some dataframes with names from a list. The current code that i have written is something like that

```
d = [[df1, 'path to datafile'],[df2,'path to data file']]
for lst in d:
 lst[0] = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
.option("header","true") \
.option("inferschema","true") \
.option("location",lst[1]) \
.load(lst[1])
display(lst[0])
```

This code works but creates dataframes with the literal names "lst[0]". I want multiple dataframes created with names df1,df2...
how can i do this in Pyspark ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem per the below code.
i had to create a dictionary and add the dataframes to that. It doesn't seem to be possible to do the same with a list. here is my code

```
frames = {}
dfgroups =[['df1','file.csv'],['df2','fil2.xlsx',"'sheet1'!A1"]....]
for grp in dfgroups:
  if grp[1].endswith('csv'):
    reader = 'csv'
    readformat = 'com.databricks.spark.csv'
  elif grp[1].endswith('xlsx'):
   reader = 'xlsx'
   readformat = 'com.crealytics.spark.excel'
   dataadr = grp[2]
   if reader == 'csv':
    df = spark.read.format(readformat) \
         .option("header","true") \
         .option("inferSchema","true") \
         .option("location",mountPath + grp[1]) \
         .load(mountPath + grp[1])
   elif reader == 'xlsx':
      df = spark.read.format(readformat) \
          .option("header","true") \
          .option("inferSchema","true") \
          .option("location",mountPath + grp[1]) \
          .option("dataAddress",dataadrs) \
          .load(mountPath + grp[1])


frames[grp[0]] = df
```

this will create dataframes for the above files and store it into the dictionary. You can also rename these dataframes individually after creation.